# Control de Administrador por subdominio

Tags: laravel, permisos

estoy usando laravel 8, Hyn (tenant) y spatie permissions.

Tengo todo funcionando pero tengo un pequeño detalle que no logro como hacerlo.

Todos los usuarios estan en la misma base de datos... los administradores tambien, pero tienen un  campo agregado que es adminuuid donde tienen un codigo ejemplo: 09a8dsa03

cada subdominio tiene un uuid... y necesito que al ingresar a sub1.dominio.com/admin solo pueda iniciar sesión quien tenga el 09a8dsa03 en el uuid... y el que tenga el as2398a solo pueda entrar a sub2.dominio.com/admin

si el usuario del sub2 entra al del sub1 pues que sea redirigido al sub1...

yo de momento detecto el uuid con esto:

```
$website   = app(\Hyn\Tenancy\Environment::class)->website();
 
        $websiteId = $website->uuid;
```

en routes tengo esto donde solamente pueden entrar los administradores... pero el problema es que todos los administradores pueden entrar al panel de todos los subdominios.

a la vez tengo instalado los roles de spatie porque a la vez cada administrador puede darle accesos extra como moderadores a otros dentro de su subdominio

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>['auth:sanctum', 'role:Admin']], function () {
    Route::get("/admin", function(){
            return View::make("adm.dashboard");
    })->name('dashboard');
```

Como podría hacer esto?

Desde ya muchisimas gracias!

Comment: tendrías que hacer un middleware adicional que compare el uuid del subdominio con el uuid del usuario logueado. Lo pondrías después de verificar el rol y en él compararías `$website->uuid` con  `auth()->user()->uuid`. Si no se cumple, retornas con una redirección